# Usar Api herramienta corrección ortográfica para integrar en SOes, para mejorar el sitio

Tags: característica-nueva

Usando la API de esta herramienta: [LanguageTool](https://www.languagetool.org/es/) podríamos mejorar en la escritura de preguntas y respuestas. Esta herramienta marca los errores ortográficos, de forma que mientras escribes puedes corregirlos. También les servirá a quienes más les cuesta escribir bien y así escribir mejor.

Comment: No me queda claro si la propuesta es que se pueda usar cualquier API de terceros o una en particular, la que mencionas, o ambas :)

Comment: ¿Esto es una propuesta para que todo Stack Exchange use corrección ortográfica en las publicaciones?

Comment: La que menciono @Rubén. Sino propusiera esta sino muchas no la propondría.

Comment: Si @Mariano esta herramienta es muy útil. El sitio mejoraría porque las preguntas y respuestas estarían corregidas previa-publicación. Considero que es un avance para esta web y cualquiera poder poner en marcha una corrección ortográfica automática.

Comment: Como todas las herramientas (o en su mayoría), tiene sus áreas de oportunidad, en este caso, solo corrige por palabras y no por el contexto completo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2F3h.png Aunque es totalmente respetable que te ayudes de cualquier tipo de herramientas, si algún usuario se siente conforme estoy seguro que la utilizará :)

Comment: Yo no me ayudo de esta herramienta, la encontré buscando una app para mac para escribir novelas, no sé como llegué allí. Mi propuesta no es para que los usuarios se ayuden con la herramienta, sino que la idea es que esta herramienta sea integrada en SOes para que al escribir la herramienta detecte errores de ortografía.

Comment: Que poco interés a generado esta cuestión que tan interesante me parece a mi.