# ¿Sería posible marcar preguntas y respuestas para que reciban corrección ortográfica?

Tags: característica-nueva

Muchas veces he encontrado preguntas y respuestas con errores ortográficos. Cuando tuve reputación suficiente para proponer correcciones traté de mejorar una publicación haciendo un par de ajustes y no pude guardar cambios por no haber cambiado suficientes caracteres. A partir de entonces me hago el de la vista gorda frente a esos errores, pero no dejan de molestarme.
El tema ya ha sido tratado: hay una pregunta similar en meta: [Are we discouraged from fixing typos and misspellings on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77233) que conocí gracias a @pykho. Y, otra local [¿Es posible realizar ediciones menores de tipo ortográfico o gramatical a las publicaciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2204/91033) por la que esta podría ser marcada como duplicada.

### Nueva funcionalidad:

No obstante, mi interés va dirigido a tratar de obtener una nueva funcionalidad: ***Poder marcar preguntas y/o respuestas con una bandera*** (especialmente cuando se trate de respuestas aceptadas) para que reciban atención y corrección ortográfica y gramatical; algo así como *"ponerlas en cola de revisión"*.

En general, no cabe esperar que los usuarios con reputación suficiente, para hacer cambios, estén al tanto de todo lo que se publica. Y, menos aún, que inviertan el tiempo que usan para aportar en temas de mayor relieve en detectar y/o hacer correcciones. De modo que sería bueno que al poderlas marcar ingresen a una "lista de espera" a la que se pueda ir (cuando se disponga de tiempo y privilegios) a hacer pequeños ajustes necesarios.
Creo que eso ayudaría a mejorar significativamente la imagen y calidad de SOes.

Comment: Si es demasiado complicado editarla puedes reportarla como baja calidad. Luego un usuario que esté en la cola de revisión va a editarla. Este usuario _moderador_ va a elegir entre votar para eliminarla o editarla. También puedes hacer una edición sugerida de al menos 6 caracteres de diferencia, si ve que tu edición es aceptable entonces la aprobará y la editará. Cuanto mejor sea la edición más probabilidad de que sea aceptada. Consejo, no hagas muchas ediciones menores porque podrían ponerte un bloqueo para editar.

Comment: @ArtEze gracias por comentar. Reportar como **baja calidad** por problemas ortográficos o gramaticales es una acusación fuerte y posiblemente injusta. Justamente por esa razón hace falta una bandera que señale la debilidad específica.

Comment: Entiendo, y también entiendo que es buena propuesta. Ahí está el problema, entre decidir si editarla uno mismo o reportar para que la edite alguien más. Hace bastantes años propusieron que esto sea integrado a un corrector auátomtico. https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1818/usar-api-herramienta-correcci%c3%b3n-ortogr%c3%a1fica-para-integrar-en-soes-para-mejorar

Comment: Por cierto, a mí me gustaría algo diferente. Desearía que se active el diff mientras estoy editando la pregunta, y no tener que verlo luego de que la pregunta esté editada en el historial de ediciones.

Comment: @ArtEze creo que reportar una pregunta que tiene problemas ortográficos simples como de *baja calidad* es un abuso de los reportes. Lo mejor en estos casos es editar la pregunta buscando otras modificaciones más significativas(Toda pregunta siempre se puede mejorar)

Comment: Diste en el punto @eyllanesc un error elemental, o unos pocos errores que no dañan el contenido de fondo, pero si **desdicen** de la calidad de la comunidad, no merecen el calificativo *baja calidad* pero deben ser marcados para ser atendidos.

Comment: @quevedo De los años que llevo en SO y de mis ediciones no he tenido problemas con manejar los *horrores* ortográficos. En muchos casos tuve que reescribir alguna otra parte de la pregunta para que la edición fuese significativa. Por otro lado si ganas la suficiente reputación puedes hacer cualquier tipo de edición aunque sean pocos caracteres

Comment: Buena idea! @eyllanesc tratar de hacer la corrección usando sinónimos para abultar los cambios y lograr que el sistema los tolere. La voy a tratar de emplear dónde sea posible.

Comment: @quevedo yo solo he tenido un caso imposible de mejorar la edición ya que el problema no solo eran *horrores* ortográficos sino que el OP parece que nunca aprendio a construir simples oraciones(no me puedo imaginar como entrega informes o trabajos) y menos a redactar y no abusar de los "...", ni sabia que la coma existe, etc

Comment: @eyllanesc En ese sentido me queda una inquietud: corregir ciertos giros gramaticales y detalles ortográficos, o aplicar formato [tag:markdown] es en general bien recibido por el OP, pero voltearle el escrito puede resultar o ser tomado como agresivo y eso me inhibe.

Comment: @quevedo No sé a que tipo de usuarios has conocido, la edición de preguntas es algo muy comun en SO por lo que no deberia generar problemas. Si sospechas que el OP lo puede tomar a mal entonces basta con señalarle que has editado la pregunta para que sea mejor recibida por la comunidad, eso deberia ser suficiente, si no lo es entonces probablemente SO no es el mejor lugar para el OP. En SO se apuesta por el trabajo grupal por lo que cualquier acción(dentro de los margenes adecuados) debe ser tomado como un acto de buena fe.

Answer (score 5):

<sup><sub>Lo habia puesto como comentario, pero mejor lo pongo como respuesta así conozco la opinión de la gente</sub></sup>

---

Me voy a centrar en el problema de la pregunta que son las ediciones demasiado cortas de las preguntas.

> Cuando tuve reputación suficiente para proponer correcciones traté de
>   mejorar una publicación haciendo un par de ajustes y **no pude guardar
>   cambios por no haber cambiado suficientes caracteres**.

Si es un error ortográfico muy grande de esos que te parpadea un ojo al verlo puedes editar la pregunta y añadir un comentario `html` que son invisibles salvo que edites la pregunta o mires el historial de edición o los trates como código.

Ejemplo:

haver |   ha<strike>v</strike>ber `<!-- Edición demasiado corta -->`

Y así cuando revise la edición alguien con mas reputación podrá "aceptar y mejorar edición" **y borrar este comentario**. (lo que yo haría)

También tienes que tener en cuenta que al poner el comentario si el que lo revisa no se da cuenta de tu intención (lo puedes comunicar en el titulo de la edición) te la pueden rechazar. Pero al menos te podrás ir con la conciencia tranquila por haberlo intentando.

Comment: ¡ Excelente ! problema resuelto. Creo que esto me va a servir, pues opera en situaciones en las que además se cuenta con poco tiempo para actuar.

Comment: Acabas de demostrar que **no se necesita la funcionalidad.**

Comment: @quevedo Espera un poco para poner la respuesta como aceptada. Igual las grandes mentes de SOes nos comentan por que esto puede ser una mala idea y por lo tanto no se debiera hacer.

Comment: OK. Ya la desacepté, a mi pesar, porque es brillante. Si hubiese una macro [macro: ajuste ortográfico] sería precioso.

Comment: Una de las cosas a tener presente es que las ediciones de los usuarios con poca  reputación pasan a la cola de revisión y quedará al criterio de los revisores el aceptar o rechazar tal sugerencia.

Comment: @Rubén Correcto, lo he tenido en cuenta pero solo había puesto el ejemplo de lo que yo haría  que sería "mejorar la edición". Si lo ve cualquier otro usuario que no se fije en la intención o que no le parezca correcto la podría rechazar.

Comment: @quevedo si yo viese ese tipo de edición en la cola de revisión lo rechazaria ya que es extraña, confusa y para mi sería ruido. Pienso que solo lo aceptarian usuarios que hayan leído este post y acepten ese tipo de mensajes ocultos.

Comment: @eyllanesc creo que si el comentario es <!-- corrección ortográfica --> el usuario a cargo de la cola de revisión (que sabe que está revisando por cuestión de privilegios) entendería que el comentario no es inocente ni mete ruido (que es comunicación con el) y que puede quitarlo y aceptar la corrección.

Comment: @Rubén si el texto es <!-- corrección ortográfica --> no creo que la decisión del usuario a cargo de la revisión sea rechazar algo que resuelve un problema evidente, simplemente quita el **rem** y aprueba, que de hecho debe ser mejor que lo que había.

Comment: @quevedo Como comente, si yo no hubiese leido esta publicación y viese ese tipo de edición entonces yo lo rechazaria. Ojala que otros usuarios no piensen lo mismo que yo :-)

Comment: @eyllanesc Ox alá!

Answer (score 1):

En mi opinión no hace falta este tipo de reporte. Si tu o alguien más ven algo que requiere corrección ortográfica, simplemente hagan la corrección.

Hay que tener presente que las ediciones deben ser significativas. Por esta razón las ediciones de para agregar un diacrítico, cambiar una letra por otro o pasar una minúscula a mayúscula están bloqueadas por el sistema. Fuera de esto, cualquiera puede sugerir una edición.

Artículo de ayuda relacionado

- [¿Por qué puede la gente editar mis mensajes? ¿Cómo funciona el trabajo de edición?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

P.D. Del artículo de ayuda anterior

> Las ediciones deben ser sustanciales y dejar la publicación mejor de como se encontró. Las razones más comunes para ediciones incluyen:
>
> - Para corregir errores gramaticales y ortográficos

Comment: La cuestión es que si te encuentras una pregunta/respuesta corta y te encuentras con Haver o Aser y editas la corrección pero no hay suficientes cambios como para poder proponerlo, ni tampoco tienes reputación suficiente. Has de quedarte observando, sin poder hacer nada mas, que escribir un comentario comentando las faltas, que puede resultar agresivo u ofensivo para el OP,  en ese caso yo creo que una opción de reporte ortográfico estaría bien.

Comment: @NicolasOñate si una pregunta es corta y tiene unos cuantos _haver_ o _aser_, creo que la mayoría de las veces será mejor votarla para cerrar.

Comment: @NicolasOñate Coincido con el comentario de fedorqui. Si tienes casos concretos que valga la pena corregir envía un reporte para la atención de un moderador ♦ . Si fueran muchos estos casos, ya quedaría en ellos respaldar esta solicitud de característica nueva.

Comment: Creo que los casos son muchos, particularmente frecuentes en estudiantes que recién inician (primeros cursos). Y, esas preguntas/respuestas se quedan así porque no se regresa sobre ellas. Pero si aparecen cuando se hace consultas relacionadas. Y, votar para cerrarlas cuando pueden resolver dudas importantes o frecuentes, puede no ser el mejor camino.

Comment: @quevedo Entiendo que a lo que se refiere fedorqui por prequntas cortas es a las que carecen de información suficiente y por ello serían cerradas independientemente de que sean "dudas importantes o frecuentes". Por cierto, si identificas dudas importantes o frecuentes que no se han preguntado con base en los lineamientos del sitio, anímate a hacer una buena pregunta y si sabes la respuesta, también a contestarla.

Comment: @Rubén el asunto es que aunque últimamente he tenido que consultar muchas preguntas por tema y he leído muchas que llevan mucho tiempo, (de todos los sabores: largas, cortas, etc.) y he notado que se quedaron tal-cual, con sus errores que desdicen del sitio. Y, sentirme maniatado, y con poca disponibilidad de tiempo para hacer algo de fondo, me trajo a proponer, pues imagino no ser único en tal situación.

Comment: @Rubén hace un momento se publicó una respuesta que **salda** el tema **demostrando que la funcionalidad no es necesaria**. Gracias por los aportes.